# AWS Aurora Support for WSO2 EI/MI/APIM/IS

Tags: wso2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Does wso2 support AWS aurora for EI 6.6.0, Identity server 5.3.x and APIM 4.0.0?

We are currently running WSO2 (EI/APIM/IS) on AWS EC2 servers and the shared Mysql DB on AWS RDS but lately we have some scalability issues with AWS RDS and we are planning to switch to AWS Aurora but we are concerned about the compatibility and support.

Is it okay to switch from AWS RDS to AWS Aurora for WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, WSO2 doesn't mention anything about supporting Aurora, but since Aurora is fully compatible with MySQL there shouldn't be an issue.